# How to write to the Firebase Realtime Database after a call to Firebase Function?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Function which creates new users once called from my mobile application. In my application there are 2 types of user roles, a Trainer (admin controls) and a Client (normal users).

The way in which i have planned to structure my database is when a Trainer account is created then their details are saved in the Realtime Database. If they then create a Client account using the Firebase Function then those created details are then saved under their data tree, an example may look like this:

```
|-Users
  |-jDY1aLVqPLXhCMZVf1jc2EqkD3R2
    |-id: "jDY1aLVqPLXhCMZVf1jc2EqkD3R2"
    |-role: "Trainer"
    |-username: "Jhon Doe"
    |-Clients
      |-5iDBxPnWU9XB0AYWTv11T1iVADl2
      :  |-id: "5iDBxPnWU9XB0AYWTv11T1iVADl2"
      :  |-role: "Client"
      :  |-username: "Sax Cooper"
      |-29TiAzSinERJi74SkMriNxQ0Vkj2
         |-id: "29TiAzSinERJi74SkMriNxQ0Vkj2"
         |-role: "Client"
         |-username: "James John"
```

**QUESTION:**

How can i add Clients details under a Trainers data tree? Because the sign up authentication of a Trainer is done in the applications Sign Up Activity, I implemented a database write into an OnCompleteListener of the authentication. However, when i add the OnCompleteListener to my HTTP Function Call, a new user is created by the Firebase Function but no details are added to the Realtime Database (the addOnCompleteListener of the returned `mFunctions` does not seem to work).

*Side Question: When the called function creates a new Client, the userID for this newly created account shows in the log of the Firebase Function console but how can i get this userID to store the details in the database as the example above?*

NewClientFragment.java:

```
public class NewClientFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;
    private String uid;
    private String email, password, displayName;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //GET THE USERID OF THE LOGGED IN TRAINER THAT IS CREATING A NEW CLIENT
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
        uid = user.getUid();

        //TEXTVIEW SETUP
        final TextView txtEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        final TextView txtDisp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dspName);
        final TextView txtPswd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.password);

        //BUTTON SETUP WHICH VALIDATES FIELD ENTRIES (NOT SHOWN IN EXAMPLE) THEN EXECUTES HTTP FUNCTION CALL
        Button addButton  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewClient);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //GET EMAIL, PASSWORD & DISPLAY NAME FROM USER INOUT
                email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                password = txtPswd.getText().toString();
                displayName = txtDisp.getText().toString();

                ...
                //IF ALL FIELDS ENTERED THEN CREATE AN ACCOUNT IN THE FIREBASE DATABASE, IF UNSUCCESSFUL THEN THROW AN ERROR
                else if (!(email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()&& displayName.isEmpty())) {
                    callCloudFunction();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    //WHEN CALLED TRIGGERS THE FUNCTION DEPLOYED TO FIREBASE FUCNTIONS WHICH CREATES NEW CLIENT USERS
    public Task<String> callCloudFunction() {
            FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("email", email);
            data.put("password", password);
            data.put("displayName", displayName);
            data.put("trainerId", uid);
            data.put("photoURL", "NULL");

            return mFunctions
                    .getHttpsCallable("mkUser")
                    .call(data)
                    .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                            return (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Sign Up Unsuccessful? Check Terms & Conditions",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                //CREATE ENTRIES INTO DATABASE THAT STORES ROLES & NEWLY CREATED USER USERS INFO
                                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Clients");


                                //ADD USER DETAILS TO FIREBASE REALTIME DATABASE FOR CHAT FEATURES & ROLE CHECK.
                                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("id", //NEED AN ANSWER TO THE SIDE QUESTION TO ENTER THIS VALUE);
                                hashMap.put("role", "Client");
                                hashMap.put("username", displayName);

                                mRef.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Sign Up successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of data redundancy in your database. Your ids are the same as your keys (so you don't need the id property) and the records in the Clients node have a role property of client (you already know they are clients cos they are in the Client's node). You are  going to end up paying Google for data storage and download that you don't need to.

Comment: @GrahamD thank you for highlighting this, that can be amended. But do you know why the OnCompleteListener above is not working?

Comment: Sorry but I don't. I use FB RTDB with Flutter/Dart.